# NetSuite not allowing request for Keys SDF

Tags: netsuite, suitescript2.0

I just started a new project, went to setup SDF and NetSuite fails on the request for Keys. I Installed the SDF Developer role and made sure all were accounted for. I used the same SDF bundle that very morning on another instance and everything went fine. On this one when I request for NetSuite to issue the token, it responds with "Two Factor Authentication required" I checked and SDF is set up correctly and the 2FA is set to not-required. I checked and made sure that it had permissions for token management, user access tokens, integration application etc, and all are set to full. I have done this many times before but I cannot figure out what it might be.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason and I found this out later, is that some permissions required may be locked down on that instance. The workaround is to take the generated keys from the access tokens that you created and put them manually into the SDF plugin, and it will then allow you to login with the IDE. After that use as normal.